# Insert new column with iterative value to every unique rows in a table using proc sql

Tags: sql, sas, proc

May I know if there's technique to insert new column with iterative value to every unique rows in a table?

Example:

TABLE HAVE

```
ID  name
1   John
2   Matt
3   Pete
```

Now, I have a counter = 3 and I want to add every counter value up to 3 to each unique ID in table HAVE.

TABLE WANT

```
ID name count
1  John 1
1  John 2
1  John 3
2  Matt 1
2  Matt 2
2  Matt 3
3  Pete 1
3  Pete 2
3  Pete 3
```

I can do this using data step using combination of by and first.var:

```
data want;
  set have;
    by ID;
  if first.ID then do;
    do i = 1 to count;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

My main issue here is the runtime, data step process a data set sequentially and may take some time to run. I want to know if this can be done using proc sql?

Comment: How about one sql statement per counter value and then a UNION of those... Such as Select ID, name, 1 as counter from blah blah UNION Select ID, Name, 2 as Counter from blah blah UNION Select ID, Name, 3 as Counter From blah blah ?

Comment: That would be a nice thing to try. I guess I'll put it inside a loop then? I'll try that approach. My main issue though is run time actually that's why I don't want to use data step as it process sequentially which takes a lot of time.

Comment: Why would it be any faster any other way ?  Is there a reason your are creating what I presume are placeholder rows for within group details ?  How wide are the records you are repeating ?  Can you create a separate table for the sequence numbered detail records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done particularly easily `proc sql` using built-in functionality.  One solution is if you have a tally or number table of some sort.  Then you could just do:

```
select id, t.name, n.n
from t join
     numbers n
     on n.n <= :counter;
```

In fact, if your ids are sequential with no gaps (as in your example), you could use a self join:

```
select t.id, t.name, n.id as count
from t join
     t n
     on n.id <= :counter;
```

If you know the specific value, you could construct a `union all` query:

```
select id, name, 1 as count from t
union all
select id, name, 2 as count from t
union all
select id, name, 3 as count from t;
```

Modern SQL now has constructs that simplify this process (window functions and recursive CTEs for instance).  However, those are not available directly in `proc sql`.

Comment: Hi Gordon! thank you for the detailed reply. Actually, the table I sampled is just a simplified version of what I'm currently working on. I guess I'll just have to stick with data step. Run time is my problem though :(

Comment: If you are reluctant to use a data step because it means reading and writing your data once more, consider busing a data step view.

Answer (score 0):

The result set is an outer join, and will contain N<sup>2</sup> rows if there are N rows all distinct.

Example:

SASHELP.CLASS has 19 distinct rows, and each row would have 18 replicates, resulting in 19**2 or 361 rows.

A helper query creates a helper table of just the `count` values (I call them `index`)

```
data class;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

proc sql; 
* monotonic() trusted by Richard for this create/select only ;
* commented out for fear of mono (pun intended);
* create table indexes as 
  select index from
  ( select distinct *, monotonic() as index from class);

  * one mark per distinct row;
  create table distinct_marks(keep=mark) as
  select distinct *, 1 as mark from class;

* create table of traditionally computed monotonic indexes;
data indexes(keep=index);
  set distinct_marks;
  index + 1;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    self.*, 
    each.index 
  from 
    class as self 
  cross join 
    indexes as each
  ;
quit;
```

Compare the above to your original approach

````
proc sql noprint;
  select count (*) into :count trimmed
  from 
  ( select distinct * from class );
quit;

data want;
  set class;
  do _n_ = 1 to &count;
    output;
  end;
run;```

Regardless of what approach you choose, OUTER JOINS can get BIG QUICK, and thus cause lots of time consuming disk i/o.
````

Comment: Hi Richard, it is my first time to encounter monotonic function in SAS. I've done some research and found that it's undocumented and may produce unwanted/missing results. Can't risk this in production. :) Anyway, I will try to play with it to discover what may trigger those events. Thank you for this! :)

Comment: You can use a DATA Step to assign the monotonic indices.  I will update answer.